# Eclipse throws "Unable to create new native thread.". How to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with Eclipse configuration and very often it throws me a message "Unable to create new native thread." and I'm prompted to restart Eclipse. I saw that there are many topics about this, but i did find anything to help me to solve my problem.

I use:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Windows 7 Ultimate
Processor: Intel Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU T5870 @ 2.20 GHz
Memory (RAM): 4.00 GB
System Type: 64-bit Operating System
```

My eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
F:/Oracle/Middleware/jdk160_29/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-server
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xss2m
-Xms1G
-Xmx1G
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
```

Comment: You should try to upgrade your JDK and Eclipse.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without loosing the configurations i did till now (for example for database connection) and installed Plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to adjust the Xss parameter? It controls how big the stack of each thread is, and with Xmx set to 1G giving 2 Mb for the stack of each thread seems too much for IDE threads in most cases.

Since you have 4G of RAM try changing:

```
-Xss2m
-Xms1G
-Xmx1G
```

with

```
-Xss512k
-Xms1G
-Xmx1512m
```

This should solve your issue or at least mitigate it a lot.

Comment: The Launcher gives me an error: "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"

Comment: I edited the answer...the idea is to find the lowest values of Xss that allows you to start the JVM with the highest value of Xmx.

Comment: Just experiment with the values keeping the overall goal in mind and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, Eclipse is started successfully. Let's hope that it will be better. I will write again to say how it's behavior after the changes we made.

Comment: I expect the problem just to be mitigated, but hey maybe it's enough. What kind of application are you developing? Something heavily multithreaded? Any chance you're leaking threads?

Comment: I am developing a web application for the university. According to me it should not be multithreaded.

Comment: Actually it is, since you're deploying on a application server which is absolutely multithreaded. The IDE itself is multithreaded. BTW you're not likely to leak any thread, so see how it goes with the updated configuration.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information and for the help. I will update you.

Comment: I got another error: Internal compiler error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble with Eclipse Luna on Fedora 20. I've read a lot about different memory options and still couldn't figure out the problem. It drove me crazy.

Finally I realized that by default, the number of processes a regular user can have on Fedora is very limited. Content of limits.d/90-nproc.conf:

```
*          soft    nproc     1000
```

Raising this to 5000 fixed my "Unable to create new native thread" problems.